# How to import '.jar' library file into Unity?

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, jar, import

How can I import to `.jar` file into Unity3D? I am using Windows platform, not Android, iOS, Mac etc. I put my `.jar` file into to the Assets/Plugins/x86. I don't understand how to call my function in `.jar` library.

I haven't found anything here for windows: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html

Thanks.

Comment: Jar files are for Java. Unity is based on .NET with native plugins too - no Java support that I'm aware of,.

Comment: But, its support Android java plugin, not suported for Windows. I dont understand...

Comment: Use JD_GUI tools to see what java classes this jar contains. If it is for Android, you can use AndroidJavaClass and AndroidJavaObject class.

Comment: Well it doesn't seem surprising that Unity on Android would support Java plugins...

Comment: Its not for android. For Windows. I dont need to JD_GUI,Because its mine library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity on Windows platform you do not have a built in support for this as far as I know, but it is easy to convert Java bytecode to .NET using [ikvm](http://www.ikvm.net/). It comes with a converter named ikvmc, so you can simply use:

```
ikvmc your.jar -target:library ==> add -target:library to generate dll
```

It will convert your jar to your.dll which is your Java code rewritten in .NET dll. Then you simply use it by putting it in your assets folder and use it as if it was native .NET library. For example, if your java code was:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

You use it simply by `HelloWorld.hello()`

Comment: Thank you, i will test it soon. :)

Comment: How can I use my dll ? In my dll functions like this;

public static boolean Test1(int N)
public static String Test2()

Comment: So you just call `YourClass.Test1(10)`, see an update to my answer

Comment: Thx, I not try it but why not I use DLLIMPORT and extern void?

Comment: Because it is needed only to import unmanaged (not .NET) libraries from .NET code, but the libraries you create with ikvmc are .NET managed libraries. See here for more info about managed plugins: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html

Comment: Is ikvmc obfuscating my library?

Comment: I am pretty sure it isn't, and it has no reason to, can't say 100% though. At least all the prototypes are not obfuscated. You can try to decompile it and see.

Comment: I tried with reflector ilspy etc. Not opened. Not need security. Its only performance lose for unity. Becouse its not public api. Thx for all again. I will test it soon

Comment: I tried it.  My TestAPI.dll in assets folder. Get this error : The name `TestAPI' does not exist in the current context. Why ?

Comment: ikvm.net is down and I need to convert a JAR to .NET DLL. So what do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly add jar files  in unity

Example class file below, compile into jar

```
package xxx;
    import android.util.Log;
    public class Helper {
    public static void testAndroid()
        {
        Log.i(“Unity”, “test android”);
        }
    }
```

Place the jar file in plugins->Android in unity and check android platform in plugin editor. Note it will only run on android device or simulator if you are using android references

Create a new MonoBehaviour script TestAndroidPlugin.cs, and attach it to the camera:

```
public class TestAndroidPlugin : MonoBehaviour {    
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log("Android function is to be called");


        var ajc = new AndroidJavaClass("xxx.Helper"); //(1)
        ajc.CallStatic("testAndroid");                                       //(2)
        Debug.Log("Androidtion is called");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have know unity does not support jar library for windows development because the supported programming language are

> UnityScript(javascript for unity), boo and C#.

You can check the documentation here
[unity supported programming language](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/09/03/documentation-unity-scripting-languages-and-you/) 
Even they drop support for booking in unity 5.0 but you can use it.  **Instead of a jar library why not look for a c# library** that solve the same problem you want to solve.